# activity with a static frame

Tags: java, android

i wanna make an activity with a keyboard [image]

i'm using a barcode scanner for read qr codes and ean and the data get matched in a db and the result is on the white part, i change the textview with the "1"

if i press the enter key i wanna show in the white part a menu or a history of the data read from the scanner without change activity (in this way i can have the scanner always with priority and override the inputs on the phone, if i change activity i have to do a copy/paste of the keyboard + scanner management and duplicate the stuff
is possible to have the left area in another activity/frame/subsomething and refresh only that area without touch the right area?

the keyboard is used in almost all the program, for this reason i made a hardcoded version, i can ignore the problem of the scanner, if i change activity, and disable it, when isn't in the main activity, but still i need to redo the keyboard, isn't a big code but if i have 10 activity i have to repeat it 10 times and if i change something on the keyboard i have to edit all

so is possible to import a sub activity with the keyboard or the white part and change it?

i know i can make a services for the scanner, but is overkill :-)
i was searching something easy that i'm missing
worst case i was thinking in a dialog but is a ugly way

Comment: You can have two [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) in one Activity side by side. One with the keyboard and one with the white area

Comment: thanks i know there was something already, i mean if you could have done it 25 yrs ago with simple plain html i don't see why now wasn't possible :-P